# Implementing Vue into existing django app

Tags: django, python-3.x, vue.js

I have an existing Django app built but I am trying to implement **vue js** into the project. I have tried some tutorials online but none seem to work of fulfilling my needs.

Can anybody recommend a good resource or tutorial to follow?

Comment: A simple search on youtube would have got the required results like: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0FTaWat_VsM

Comment: Thank you for this. I did not find this video when I searched.

Comment: Np. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple search on youtube would have got the required results like: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0FTaWat_VsM Answer courtesy of Abijith Mg